# Write feature matches to file in ascending order

Tags: c++, opencv, dictionary, indexing

I import feature matches from a specific algorithm and the features are stored as four point coordinates (x1, y1, x2, y2). Now I want to give every feature a unique index and store it in a matches.txt file.

A minimal example could look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

struct Image {
    // ...
    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, cv::Point2f> feature_matches;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> all_matches;
    // ..
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    // 4 images and matches between them 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4, 3-4 - in sum 23 matches
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Vec4f>> matches;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4f> matches_12(4); matches.push_back(matches_12);
    std::vector<cv::Vec4f> matches_13(2); matches.push_back(matches_13);
    std::vector<cv::Vec4f> matches_14(5); matches.push_back(matches_14);
    std::vector<cv::Vec4f> matches_23(7); matches.push_back(matches_23);
    std::vector<cv::Vec4f> matches_24(1); matches.push_back(matches_24);
    std::vector<cv::Vec4f> matches_34(4); matches.push_back(matches_34);

    // I read the matches usually via filestream and store them with an incrementing counter in feature_matches
    // For the minimal example I push the matches vector into a similar structure - point coordinates are irrelevant
    int num_images = 4;
    int counter = 0;
    std::vector<Image> images(num_images);
    // Iterate through all combinations of images 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < images.size(); ++i) {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < images.size(); ++j) {

            if (i == 0) {
                for (size_t k = 0; k < matches[j + i-1].size(); ++k) {
                    // Create two Points for both images and push them into the feature matches vector
                    cv::Point2f point_image_i = cv::Point2f(matches[j + i - 1][k][0], matches[j + i - 1][k][1]);
                    cv::Point2f point_image_j = cv::Point2f(matches[j + i - 1][k][0], matches[j + i - 1][k][1]);
                    images[i].feature_matches.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(j, counter), cv::Point2f(point_image_i.x, point_image_i.y)));
                    images[j].feature_matches.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(i, counter), cv::Point2f(point_image_j.x, point_image_j.y)));
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            else {
                for (size_t k = 0; k < matches[j + i].size(); ++k) {
                    cv::Point2f point_image_i = cv::Point2f(matches[j + i][k][0], matches[j + i][k][1]);
                    cv::Point2f point_image_j = cv::Point2f(matches[j + i][k][0], matches[j + i][k][1]);
                    images[i].feature_matches.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(j, counter), cv::Point2f(point_image_i.x, point_image_i.y)));
                    images[j].feature_matches.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(i, counter), cv::Point2f(point_image_j.x, point_image_j.y)));
                    counter++;
                }
            }           
        }
    }

    /* (size_t i = 0; i < images.size(); ++i) {
        for (auto[ID, Point] : images[i].feature_matches) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
            std::cout << ID.first << " " << ID.second << " " << Point.x << " " << Point.y << "\n";
        }
    }*/
}
```

The matches file (.txt file) needs to look like that:
Image numbers starting from 1! Matches start with 0 with ascending order and incrementing number between different pairs (so e.g. 2.jpg 3.jpg starts with "4" because there are already 4 matches in 1.jpg 2.jpg).

```
1.jpg 2.jpg
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
1.jpg 3.jpg
4 0
5 1
1.jpg 4.jpg
6 0
7 1
8 2
9 3
10 4
2.jpg 3.jpg
4 2
5 3
6 4
7 5
8 6
9 7
10 8
2.jpg 4.jpg
11 5
3.jpg 4.jpg
9 6
10 7
11 8
12 9
```

Now I am struggling to find a solution to this problem since a few days. I tried saving the matches in a different structure, used `std::find` and `std::iota` on the feature_matches but I am not getting the right relationship or rather keep track of the right index (especially when the first image changes, e.g. 2-3). For me, it feels like an easy problem for a programmer but I am just a beginner ;).

```
std::ofstream matches_file;
matches_file.open("matches.txt");
for (size_t i = 0; i < images.size(); ++i) {
    for (size_t j = i + 1; j < images.size(); ++j) {
        matches_file << i + 1 << ".jpg " << j + 1 << ".jpg \n";
        // .. I tried saving the matches in a different structure, experimented with std::iota and std::find to get the right sequence but I had no success
        // I think there must be a smarter solution         
    }
}
matches_file.close();
```

Comment said I should show what I have tried even if I clearly see the wrong results in my resulting text file:

```
std::ofstream matches_file;
    matches_file.open("matches.txt");
    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> IDS;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < images.size(); ++i) {
        int ref_cam_ID = i;
        for (auto [ID, Point] : images[i].feature_matches) {
            matches_file << i << ".jpg " << ID.first << ".jpg " << "\n"; 
            // This should not be printed in every loop but how can I get the reference from image 1.jpg to 2.jpg in the outer loop

            matches_file << images[ref_cam_ID].feature_matches.find(std::make_pair(ID.first, ID.second))->first.second << "\n"; 
            matches_file << images[ID.first].feature_matches.find(std::make_pair(ref_cam_ID, ID.second))->first.second << "\n";
            // Clearly this only gives me the same ID 
        }
    }
    matches_file.close();
```

Comment: Please describe the format of the output file and perhaps also what are you struggling with. What are the results you are getting?

Comment: I made the changes you were asking for.